# Retrieving firebase data into custom table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview

I am working on a `ios` application. I have a custom table cell in which my parameters are defined. I also have two labels in my prototype cell (name and author). I want the string values for name and author to be read from the database into the labels for the array.

However, i am stuck on how to append string values from `firebase` into these labels. Please help.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,
UITableViewDataSource{
    var ref:DatabaseReference!
    var books = [Books]()
  @IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        mainTableView.reloadData()
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainTableView.rowHeight = 120
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //Set the firebase reference
        Database.database().reference()
        //retrieve the posts and listen for changes
        ref?.child("Books").observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
            let post = snapshot.value as? String
             if let actualPost = post {
        self.post.append(actualPost)
            self.mainTableView.reloadData()
}
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let bookCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        let idx:Int = indexPath.row
        bookCell.bookName?.text = books[idx].name
        bookCell.bookAuthor?.text = books[idx].author
        return bookCell
    }
```

Comment: First, you should fix your code: for example, `var books[Books] = []` will not compile. Second, do you want to work with `books` (an array of `Books`, I assume) or with Strings you get from firebase - and what is `selfPost`?

Comment: please review my code. And yes, i want to work with an array of books derive from the string data in firebase

Comment: You still use `post` in your observer closure, but in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` you work with the `books` array. So how do you transform the `String` value into the a `Book`? Once you have a book, you would add it to the array of books and then refresh the UI.

Comment: do you know any helpful link you would like to share?

Answer (score 0):

The neat way to do it is define a `Class` for your type. I understand that you are presenting the books that an author has written and the authors name:

```
Class Book {

 var booksWritten:[Array]?
 var authorsName:String?

 init(booksFromFB:[Array], nameFromFB:String) {
 self.booksWritten = booksFromFB
 self.authorsName = nameFromFB
 }
}
```

In your ViewController where you call the Firebase you declare a variable that is an array of `Book`s.

```
var books = [Books]()
```

When you get the snapshot back from Firebase you initialise a variable of type Book with the properties of that record:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
ref?.child("Books").observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else { return }
for book in snapshot {
      let books = book.childSnapshot(forPath: "Books").value as? [String]
      let author = book.childSnapshot(forPath: "Author").value as? String

 let book = Book(booksFromFB: books, authorFromFB: author)
 books.append(book)
}
        self.mainTableView.reloadData()

}) { (error) in
print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

For your cell i would create a Class. (Don't forget to set its identifier in the storyboard)

```
class BooksTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var books: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var author: UILabel!

  func configureCell(books:Array, author:String){
    self.books.flatMap({$0}).joined() = books
    self.author.text=author
  }
}
```

Final step:

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
    guard let cell = mainTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BooksTableViewCell") as? BooksTableViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

    let book = books[indexPath.row]
    cell.configureCell(books: book.booksWritten, author: book.authorsName)

    return cell
}
```

PS: Don't forget to remove any observers when you no longer need them.